# Slide up/down animation with fadein/out effect

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, angular6

I have implemented an animation using angular 6 animations, animation is of type **slide up/down** along with **fading** effect but my concern is it's not behaving as intended.

Here is the sandBox for the same.
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-vmw5t

Here is how it looks currently.

[image]

My concern here is `:enter` animation is working fine, as element appears from bottom once animation begins, but as soon as I click on the **cross-icon** on the **top-right** of button, then element goes slightly up and then fade in the **bottom**.

Expected behaviour should be , as soon as **cross-icon** is clicked button from it's current position should go to bottom and fades, I want to eliminate this slight up movement of button as soon as I click `cross-icon`, instead it should fade to bottom from its current position.

**Summary:**
Fade out / slide down animation is not working properly as soon as user clicks `cross-icon` *button goes slightly up and then goes down and then fades, instead it should go down from its current position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An animation like

```
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('in', style({ opacity:1,transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity:0,transform: 'translateY(100%)' }),
        animate(200)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(200, style({ opacity:0,transform: 'translateY(100%)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

must make the job in a .html like

```
  <button (click)="toogle=!toogle">click</button>
  <div [@flyInOut] *ngIf="toogle" >
    hello word <button (click)="toogle=false">x</button>
  </div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evvxbz-e1xdz6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: looks good but when I added the same logic in my sandbox, it is not behaving exactly can you check, here -  https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-vmw5t

Comment: My stackblitz use Angular 8 -I supouse Angular 7 work too- yours use Angular 5

Comment: So, can you tell me how to fix the same, although I don't think version has any relation to it, Even I am willing to change my version.

Comment: yes, Your'e ok, I updated my stackblitz and work properly, but I can not make the code work in codesandbox

Comment: I got it!, https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-60nrr. Change the order of animate/style in `transition('* => void')` and remove the part of background